# Is it possible to write directly to a file hosted in gcp using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to know if there is any way to directly write to a file hosted in GCP/Google cloud storage bucket. Ideally we would like to write to the file using nodejs but  open to explore other technologies too.

We are getting a request in NodeJS router method and we want to write the request content to a file in GCP bucket.It looks to me that only way to write to a file in gcp bucket is by uploading a file but we would like to see if there is any way to write to the file without having to upload the file.

Is there any way we can do this? any pointers or links will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

May i point you in the direction of [file.createWriteStream](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream) where you can create a writable stream to pipe to a file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

const file = myBucket.file('my-file');

fs.createReadStream('/path')
  .pipe(file.createWriteStream())
  .on('error', function(err) {})
  .on('finish', function() {
    // The file upload is complete.
  });
```

Comment: Danstarns - if i understand this right you are asking me to read the file in '/path' and then upload that data into bucket..am i right?  but I want to see if we can write the contents from request object directly in to the bucket without having to upload a file or read from a file.

Comment: In node, a 'request' is just a [readStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) so you can replace the ```fs.createReadStream('/path')``` with the content from your http stream

Answer (score 2):

Since you are open to other tools, how about mount the bucket into local file system using [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse), then you can just write to the mount point in your nodejs request and let gcsfuse to do the upload part.